# Merge two Xcode projects into a single Build

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have two Xcode projects:

1.OLEiPhone,
  2.OLEiPad.

OLEiPhone uses iOS Slide Menu animation (left to right slide). OLEiPad uses UISplitViewController. I want to combine these two Xcode projects (OLEiPhone and OLEiPad) into a single one as a universal project. We added these two projects into our workspace, after that I don't know how to merge these two projects. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

### There are three ways to manage this projects

1. two targets in a same project.
2. two schemes in a same target
3. one schemes in a same target

If there are so many differences between iPhone and iPad versions, I prefer the first method. but it's not so easy to control. if you fall into this situation, you might need use framework or CocoaPods to manage.

If there are just a few differences as you said `UISplitViewController` or `slider`. you can manage it by two schemes. you can manage different features with MACROs .
OR 
The third method can make you make a real universal app as the Xcode demo universal one.

In all these methods, I don't think there is a way to automatically merge your two projects. But it's a chance to reorganize code.